# How can I interpret KNN clustering using FNN package in R for analyzing football passes?

Tags: r, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a dataframe of 411 rows where each row represents a pass (football) and four columns. Two columns are the x and y coordinates of the location where the pass starts, and the other two columns are the x and y coordinates of the location where the pass ends.

I am trying to implement pseudocode from an academic paper which applies nearest neighbours to the passes - this is all the information I am given. My goal is to find the nearest neighbours using all of the information: that is, by using the information of all the coordinates such that neighbours are found by accounting for start and end coordinates together.

I apply KNN (with an arbitrary k) in the following manner:

```
start_coordinates <- df[, c("location.x", "location.y")]

end_coordinates <- df[, c("end_location.x", "end_location.y")]

k = 17

nearest_neighbours <- get.knnx(start_coordinates, end_coordinates, k = k)
```

`nearest_neigbours` provides me with the index of the 17 nearest neighbours for each pass, as well as the distances. However, I am unsure whether providing the start locations as the data and the end locations as the query achieves what I describe above. If someone could provide some insights as to what this piece of code achieves, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!